# How can cancelling DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs replace all event handlers with itself?

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview, callback

I'm having a very strange problem in a VB application. I have a function written like this:

In the innermost condition, two statements are commented out here. These were found to have no effect on the strange behaviour. This is the minimal example I've found causing trouble.

(Note that the names of objects have been changed in this example.)

```
Private Sub MyForm_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles myDGV.CellValidating
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    Select Case dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
        Case "uniqueColumn"
            ' Validate that the values in our unique column are unique. 
            For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
                If i <> e.RowIndex Then
                    ' Here i != j, so compare to the value... 
                    If e.FormattedValue = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                        'dgv.ShowRowErrors = True
                        'dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Data in the unique column must be unique"
                    End If
                End If
            Next 'i
        Case Else
            ' Perform no validation. 
    End Select

End Sub
```

What trouble, you ask? For some inexplicable reason, whenever the line

```
e.Cancel = True
```

is executed, afterwards, nearly all buttons and form widgets in the **entire application**, including even the close button in its window bar (what a user would use to exit the application) stop doing whatever they previously did and now call this event handler instead.

In other words, commenting out that line (and doing the validation manually when the form is submitted) fixes the problems. I'd like to know why this happens, though. Some pointers:

Here's a list of which things are **not** affected:

- The minimize and maximize button in the top bar.
- All objects in its menu bar.

This handler is private to its form class, it's not referenced anywhere else in the application.

I'm at a loss. Just how? What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.Cancel` is for stopping the validation when the input is deemed incorrect. This causes the cell to still have focus as the user is expected to correct whatever they did wrong. The `CellValidating` event will then be raised again whenever the cell is about to lose focus until your code deems the input to be correct.

You can use the [**`Control.CausesValidation` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) to control whether a control (for instance a button) should raise validation events when it gains focus.

Comment: So in essence, the control still exists, even if its parent form is closed, and has focus. This invisible control is catching all the click events. I can chalk up the menu bar not taking focus to microsoft design-by-committee inconsistency?

Comment: @aphid : No the control doesn't exist after the form is closed unless you reference it somewhere else. The event will however be raised when the form _is about to close_ when a cell has focus. Are you saying the event is raised even after you've closed the form?

Comment: Yes. That was the user's problem; the application became effectively unresponsive because of it. I've resolved the issue, I merely wanted to know why it occurred. It's likely the forms are kept in memory even when closed in this application. There's few of them so this memory usage is not really a big issue.